# Waveshare 4.3inch HDMI LCD shows blank white screen

Tags: hdmi, display, touchscreen, lcd

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 model B running the latest version of Rasbian Stretch. 
Yesterday I've received my Waveshare 4,3 inch display. First thing I did was build it in my project, due to save height I've desoldered the connector because it's only for 5/3,3v GND and touch. I've soldered wires to the PI and installed all of the drives, and set up the config.txt like the [example](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/4.3inch_HDMI_LCD)  given. But I got an instant white screen, so backlight works but no info. However on a normal monitor there is info. And touch seems to work.

So I decided to install their distribution given on the CD which I've received with the screen. But same story, again no info on screen and with a monitor everything works.

I am quite sure I did everything I had to do: The RPi does output on HDMI, otherwise it wouldnt work with a monitor. The HDMI cable seems to be fine, otherwise it wouldn't work either. The touch screen works. All IC's recieve their 3,3 or 5 v input. I've installed all of the drivers.

How can I fix the blank white screen?

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your question a bit, hope you don't mind.

Comment: thank you Fabian, no i don't mind it :)  I wrote it pretty fast so didn't really paid attention to the grammar. more to what I tried to bring over.

Answer (score 1):

so the solution to this problem was very simple, in the HDMI connector had some dust build up, I deciced that i didn't do anything wrong, drivers where installed I knew that HDMI out works and that the cable was okay, So i tried, with special degreaser, to clean the whole unit, including the connector, and as expected the Display turned on.

welcome to an good old day in Electronics.....